# How to Edit/Update a row in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, datagridview

I m working on a shopping cart like Form in WF. I have a `DataGridView` an `ADD_Button` and `Submit_Button`.The user will choose Items From inventory and Click `ADD_Button`The item will go into `DataGridView` After Finishing User will click `Submit_Button` then detail will go into DB.

Question: is this After adding a product/row into `DatagridView` When I add same product again.it goes into the new row I want that Where `Pro_ID` Column Match, The row update with new qty. I tried to search the web but all I got SQL queries.

```
 private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            i = dgv_Purchase.Rows.Count;
            try
            {
                dgv_Purchase.Rows.Add();
                            .......
                            .......
                dgv_Purchase.Rows[i - 1].Cells["Pro_ID"].Value = txt_ProID.Text;
                            .......
                            .......

                dgv_Purchase.Rows[i - 1].Cells["Purchase_Qty"].Value = txt_Qty.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception ){}

     }
```

This is Submit Button Code

private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PRMSConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlTransaction objTransaction;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_Purchase.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            //SomeCode part of code
            SqlCommand objCmd2;
            string cmd2 = "INSERT INTO PurchaseMaster " +
                        " (Pro_ID , category_ID, Purchase_Qty) " +
                "VALUES (@Pro_ID, @category_ID, @Purchase_Qty)";
            objCmd2 = new SqlCommand(cmd2, con, objTransaction);

            objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pro_ID_ID", dgv_Purchase.Rows[i].Cells["Pro_ID"].Value.ToString());
            objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category_ID", dgv_Purchase.Rows[i].Cells["Category_ID"].Value.ToString());


            objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purchase_Qty", Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Purchase.Rows[i].Cells["Purchase_Qty"].Value.ToString()));
            objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Today", Convert.ToDateTime(dgv_Purchase.Rows[i].Cells["Purchase_Date"].Value.ToString()));
                                    ...........................
                                    Rest of the Code
                                    ...........................
            try
            {
                objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                objTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception) {}
         } 
     }
```

Comment: Where do you want to insert? into the db or datagrid? because inserting into the db is of course sql...

Comment: i m inserting in `DataGridView`and also want to Update where `Pro_ID` match if user insert Same product again.

Comment: so for example you have 3 items in your dgv which have the `Pro_ID` = `110` and when the user adds a fourth row with the id 110 but with different information you want to insert those information in all of the 3 above rows? I'm sorry but your question is not really clear to me. That is what Marcos's answer is doing

Comment: Why would be there 3 rows with `Pro_ID = 110`.If a user already inserted `Pro_ID = 110`.Second time if he enters same product i want it only update existing `Pro_ID = 110` in `DataGridView` with new information like updated qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void AddInfo()
{
    // flag so we know if there was one dupe
    bool updated = false;

    // go through every row
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Purchase.Rows)
    {
        // check if there already is a row with the same id
        if (row.Cells["Pro_ID"].ToString() == txt_ProID.Text)
        {
            // update your row
            row.Cells["Purchase_Qty"] = txt_Qty.Text;

            updated = true;
            break; // no need to go any further
        }
    }

    // if not found, so it's a new one
    if (!updated)
    {
        int index = dgv_Purchase.Rows.Add();

        dgv_Purchase.Rows[index].Cells["Purchase_Qty"].Value = txt_Qty.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you method but as you know when app starts there is no row in datagrid so i m getting NullRefrenceException.i m stuck here

Comment: @i1yas Where are you getting it? If it has no rows then it won't go through the for loop, it just adds a new row... unless you the the `NullRefrenceException` because `dgv_Purchase` is not initialized, then of course you can't work with it if it's not there..

Comment: I used Breakpoints to debug and i m getting inside `foreach` `if` statement.Also i tried to count rows inside and it is giving me  count `1`

Comment: @i1yas but then you have rows... but not with the right cells. just check befor the if, if there are cells called `Pro_ID` or `Purchase_Qty`, if not, skip

Comment: if i do `datagridview1.AllowUsertoAddrows=false` i don't get NullRefrenceException.does it looks familiar to you?

Comment: @i1yas There is no reason for this method to run at startup. As I said, check if the cells exist beforehand, then do the `if` check

Comment: Well i did this i count rows which is 1 then i make an instance of `dt` of dataTable and make it `dt=(DataTable) datagridview1` and run program in dedug mode to look inside `dt` and it showing `null`
also i checked cells they are right

Comment: I just convert `if` statement in `Foreach` to `if elseif` before `else` part i did `if (dr.Cells["Med_ID"].Value == null)
                {
                    break;
                }` after `else` your `if statement`.
it is working now

Comment: @i1yas nice, if my answer helped you, make sure to mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I edit it with a DGVrow instead of DataRow

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (dr.Cells["Pro_ID"].Value.ToString() == txt_ProID.Text)
        {                      
                    dr.Cells["Purchase_Qty"].Value = txt_Qty.Text;
                }
            }
```